# ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Middleware has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

Currently learning React JS, I am still newbie regarding these technologies.

After updating the webpack from 4.30.0 to 5.10.0 then I run `npm start`, some errors appeared as below. I have tried to delete `node_modules` and reinstall, then `npm start`, it doesn't change anything.

Dependencies :

```
"webpack": "^5.10.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "4.0.2",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.25.0",
"webpack-pwa-manifest": "4.3.0",
```

Error :
[image: 1]

Comment: Share the code you use `webpack-dev-middleware`.

Comment: di du find the answer? i am now stuck at the same place

Comment: Also in the same boat.

Comment: @Raj sorry for my late reply, I didn't find the right answer. I just downgrade it

Comment: I use `"webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.3"` and I get **options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'.**

Answer (score 1):

Solved similar issue with upgrading

```
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
```

I believe 3.x is not fully compatible.

Comment: How do you upgrade it, do I write: `npm install webpack-dev-server@4.0.0` in terminal vuejs? Yes it did upgrade it but I still get same error when doing **npm run serve** I get **options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'.**